# Efficient way to handle group of ids in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'caseid': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    'timestamp': [10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30] 
    'var1': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 10, np.nan, 11, 12, 13, 14],
    'var2': [2., 3., 4., np.nan, 5., 6., np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
    })
```

I need to find the first (and last) valid timestamp for each variable per `caseid`. I.e. For `var1`, `caseid` 1 it would be `None`, for `caseid` 2 it would be `10` (last `30`). And the same for each additional var column.

Is there handle groups of ids without looping over `caseid` and doing a `first_valid_index()` on each column, since loops not most efficient when using pandas?

Comment: Can you provide the explicit expected output for completeness?

Comment: Your provided output is suitable. I marked it as the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select the desired columns with [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) (or manually), then replace the non-NA values with the timestamp (using [`mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) and [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)), finally use a [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) with [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.first.html)/[`last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.last.html):

```
m = df.filter(like='var').notna()

out = (m.mul(df['timestamp'], axis=0).where(m)
        .groupby(df['caseid']).agg(['first', 'last'])
      )
```

Output:

```
        var1        var2      
       first  last first  last
caseid                        
1        NaN   NaN  10.0  30.0
2       10.0  30.0  20.0  30.0
3       10.0  30.0   NaN   NaN
```

Intermediate:

```
m.mul(df['timestamp'], axis=0).where(m)

   var1  var2
0   NaN  10.0
1   NaN  20.0
2   NaN  30.0
3  10.0   NaN
4   NaN  20.0
5  30.0  30.0
6  10.0   NaN
7  20.0   NaN
8  30.0   NaN
```

Comment: I believe this solution assumes that `timestamp` is sorted. If not, `df.sort_values(['caseid', 'timestamp'], inplace=True)` should do that

Comment: Indeed, it does (I assumed this was a prerequisite given the example).